# Extended Security Release confusion. Which version?

Tags: core

The information available about the Extended Security Release - https://civicrm.org/esr - states that "The latest release of ESR is version 5.7". However I can see via the system status page on a few of my sites that 5.13.6 appears to be available, but only as part of the Extended Security Release.
Can both of these bits of information be true?

Answer (score 3):

Based on some posts in chat it sounds like both 5.7 and 5.13 are current ESR, with 5.7 supported for another month or so. The webpage seems out of date a little.